# Use Redis to track concurrent outbound HTTP requests

Tags: redis

I'm a little new to Redis, but I'd like to see if it can be used to keep track of how many concurrent HTTP connections I'm making.

Here's the high level plan:

```
INCR requests
// request begins
HTTP.get(...)
// request ends
DECR.requests
```

Then at any point, just call `GET requests` to see how many are currently open.

The ultimate goal here is to throttle my http requests to stay below some arbitrary amount, say 50 requests/s.

Is this the right way to do it? Are there any pitfalls?

Answer (score 0):

As for pitfalls, the only one I can see is that a server that goes down or loses connection to Redis mid-request may never call `DECR`.

Since you don't know which server does which request, you can never reset the count to the correct value without bringing the system to a halt and reset to 0.

Comment: would a queue with expiring messages be better? Push to the queue when a connection begins, pop the queue when it finishes, and expire the message if it's there for more than, say, 60 seconds. To get concurrent connections, just get the size of the queue.

Comment: @user94154 I can't remember expiring queue messages being an option in Redis, but yes, if that is possible (been an API version or two since I used it), it sounds better.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear what you'd gain by using redis in this situation.  It seems to me it would be more suitable to use just a global variable in your server.  If your server goes down, so does your counter, so you don't have to put complicated things in place to deal with disconnection, inconsistencies, etc...

Comment: You're assuming my requests are coming from a single server. This is a textbook case for where something like Redis comes in handy.

Comment: I would just throttle per server, and trust the load balancer to evenly distribute requests.  I would not worry to be exactly at x request/seconds overall.  A lot simpler, nothing that can go wrong.